# Trouble with mySQL AND OR statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql statement that is giving me an error. It looks right to me but obviously I am missing something and I keep failing to see it. My code is such

```
$PlusHour = date('gA', strtotime("+1 hours"));

$Plus30 = date('g:30A', strtotime("+1 hours"));

$SearchDate = "CURDATE()";

$sqlCount = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM ServiceTickets WHERE Date= $SearchDate AND Time= $PlusHour OR Time= $Plus30 AND JobStatus= '1' OR JobStatus= '3' ";

$CountQuery = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sqlCount) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($db_conx));

$rowCount = mysqli_fetch_row($CountQuery);
```

The error I get is

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '*) FROM ServiceTickets WHERE Date= 2018-03-15 AND Time= 11PM OR
>   Time= 11:30PM AN' at line 1

What am I doing wrong here. Is there a problem with how my AND OR is structured?

Comment: please don't take this habit Date= $SearchDate or column=$variable in general, use prepared statment.Bye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is white space in your query at  `COUNT (*)`.

Please remove that only.

You also need to have quotes around `$PlusHour` and `$Plus30`

Your query will be like,

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ServiceTickets WHERE Date= $SearchDate AND Time= '$PlusHour' OR Time= '$Plus30'r AND JobStatus= '1' OR JobStatus= '3' "
```

Comment: Ha! Its amazing what a different pair of eyes will see when you stare at something too long. Thanks a bunch however now its giving me an error at `:30PM AND JobStatus= '1' OR JobStatus= '3'' at line 1`

Comment: No quotes required for $SearchDate, it is set to CURDATE() which needs to be unquoted to be evaluated.